# Video calling sdk for flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I want to add video and audio calling feature in my flutter application, So I want to know which SDK is supported for flutter app so that I don't have to maintain different code for android and iOS.
Can anyone suggest for which sdk should I go?
My requirements
1. should have support for flutter app.
2. view should be customizable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Agora's Flutter SDK. It provides you with lots of customizable options and a support for best in class audio/video quality. You can refer this link to view the SDK : [Agora Flutter SDK](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Flutter-SDK).

You can also view some sample apps built over here to get started with your flutter app: [1:1 Video Calling App](https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-videocall-demo), [Interactive Broadcasting](https://github.com/Meherdeep/Interactive-Broadcasting), [Group calling](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

For voice calls, you could use *[Flutter Call Kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_call_kit)* packages or any other similiar packages. But no, it only works for iOS.

I still don't know is there any packages to make a video call